# Outlook Auto-Resolving Alias to Primary Address, need disabled

Tags: autocomplete, outlook, exchange-server

Outlook 2007...

On my PC when I send an email to the address call it testemail@test.com, our exhcange server has this as an alias to the inbox call it mainbox@test.com. My outlook will leave the TO field as testmail@test.com when sending an email, which is what I need it to do. However, on another employee's PC outlook will automatically resolve testemail@test.com to mainbox@test.com when selecting another field (subject/body/etc) and send it directly to mainbox@test.com instead of testmail@test.com. I think it's using our "Global Address Book" to resolve...I just can't figure out the setting.

I have programmed a software suite to pull the TO address to determine a folder location to save emails sent to the specific alias address so that emails sent to this specific alias will get filed correctly for the alias. We have several different 'clients' that have a unique alias to reach us, but we need to have the exchange server resolve them to 1 address mailbox (to make it easier on the software suite)....the only problem i'm running into is our internal Outlook clients auto-resolving the address before they get sent to exchange.

How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2016, go to Options > Mail > Send Messages (about half way down) > Untick "Automatic name checking".

In other versions it may be called "Resolve names automatically".